# Sqoop import from impala

Tags: export, sqoop

I want to export data from impala table to oracle. I am using the following code in a script file

```
***sqoop_jdbc_url=URL
sqoop_username=username
sqoop_password=pass
field_delimiter=\|
hbase_zookeeper_property_clientPort=2181
HDFS_HOME=/user/ser_pfapp_mr
echo "running sqoop export"
sqoop export --connect $sqoop_jdbc_url --username $sqoop_username --password $sqoop_password \
--export-dir '/user/hive/warehouse/database_name.db/tablename' \
--table oracle_tableName \
--columns CUSTOMER_NUMBER,CLIENT_NUMBER,ADDRESS_TYPE,ADDRESS_LINE1,ADDRESS_LINE2,ADDRESS_LINE3,CITY,STATE,COUNTRY,ZIP \
--fields-terminated-by "$field_delimiter" \
--verbose***
```

I am getting the following error while executing the above

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Ysg.png)

I understand that Impala data resides in Hive warehouse hence I am using hive path in above code...

Answer (score 0):

The logs states sqoop is unable to connect to the right hive location. I believe you need to check and connect to the right hive server.

As an alternative, i would suggest you try to connect using [HCatalog](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_sqoop_hcatalog_integration) feature of sqoop.